# How to configure IIS 7.5 to run multiple websites on localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, configuration, localhost

I have got two website which runs on for instance http://localhost:3452 & http://localhost:5234

When I press F5 in VS2010, I am wondering if I can set both the website on IIS so that I can just type something like `http://Website1` and `http://Website2` to play with both the website, instead of debugging everytime?

Is there a way to acheive this?

I tried to add a website on IIS with no success by following simple steps :

1. RightClick on Sites > Add Website,
2. Sitename: Website1 , ApplicationPool: DefaultApp pool , PhysicalPath: Path to the Website, Press ok.
3. Now in the browser I tried something like: http://Website1 which comes up with the error below.

Any suggestions or alternatives on how to achieve this?

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>   This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the following

```
127.0.0.1  website1
127.0.0.1  website2
```

UAC may block you so you'll need to open notepad as administrator to edit the file.

In IIS change the bindings on the website so it binds to all ip addresses on port 80 but with the host header set to website1. do the same for website2.

Now you can browse to either http://website1 or http://website2

This will only work on your machine of course

Comment: Instructions for [adding bindings in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=WS.10).aspx)

Comment: as in every computer on the subnet? you'd have to modify every machine individually, so it would be easier to do it in DNS, but with different DNS addresses, then yes it would work